# C# to close Microsoft WORD document that was created but was never saved

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

My following code creates a WORD document that my `C#` code can edit. But if an error occurs I want to close the doc in the `catch` block of `try-catch` statement. Question: How can we programmatically close it. I know [how to close it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-close-documents?view=vs-2019) when a document is saved on a hard disk and you know the path of the doc?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application myWordApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document tempDoc = myWordApp.Documents.Add(Visible: false);
```

Comment: Why can't you use this: `object doNotSaveChanges =` `Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges; 
tempDoc.Close(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);`?

Comment: would tempDoc.Close(); be an option?

Comment: What kind of error are you thinking about? Please give one or more examples.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work... Are there any special requirements not included in your Question?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word;

namespace WordAddIn1
{
  public partial class ThisAddIn
  {
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      var app = Application;
      var doc = app.Documents.Add(Visible: false);

      doc.Close();

      var docCount = Application.Documents.Count ; // =0
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #region Von VSTO generierter Code

    /// <summary>
    /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
    /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
      this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
      this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```